# Broken XML file parsing and using XPATH

Tags: python, xml

I am sniffing packets on the network and recovering the XML data from the raw payload using Scapy and Python. The XML data I get has a few tags missing when I assemble the frames.Thus, I cannot parse the XML file using etree.parse() function. Is there any method by which I can parse the broken XML file and use XPATH expressions to traverse and get the data I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure my solution is far too simple to cover all cases, but it should be able to cover simple cases when closing tags are missing:

```
>>> def fix_xml(string):
    """
    Tries to insert missing closing XML tags
    """
    error = True
    while error:
        try:
            # Put one tag per line
            string = string.replace('>', '>\n').replace('\n\n', '\n')
            root = etree.fromstring(string)
            error = False
        except etree.XMLSyntaxError as exc:
            text = str(exc)
            pattern = "Opening and ending tag mismatch: (\w+) line (\d+) and (\w+), line (\d+), column (\d+)"
            m = re.match(pattern, text)
            if m:
                # Retrieve where error took place
                missing, l1, closing, l2, c2 = m.groups()
                l1, l2, c2 = int(l1), int(l2), int(c2)
                lines = string.split('\n')
                print 'Adding closing tag <{0}> at line {1}'.format(missing, l2)
                missing_line = lines[l2 - 1]
                # Modified line goes back to where it was
                lines[l2 - 1] = missing_line.replace('</{0}>'.format(closing), '</{0}></{1}>'.format(missing, closing))
                string = '\n'.join(lines)
            else:
                raise
    print string
```

This seems to add correctly missing tags B and C:

```
>>> s = """<A>
  <B>
    <C>
  </B>
  <B></A>"""
>>> fix_xml(s)
Adding closing tag <C> at line 4
Adding closing tag <B> at line 7
<A>
  <B>
    <C>
  </C>
</B>
  <B>
</B>
</A>
```